# Block single page with NoScript?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, web-filtering, noscript

I use a page with a very annoying alert onLoad, I'd like to block JavaScript on that site (it's `http://example.com/home.jsf`), but I need JS to use the rest of the web-app.

Can I block scripts only on home.jsf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it with NoScript, but you might be able to do it with  [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) by replacing the function or clearing the onLoad.

Comment: i think GM is fired after the page has already loaded, can I really stop this alert?

Comment: The [GreaseMonkey uses DOMContentLoaded](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded) ; this fires before `window.onLoad`, which doesn't fire until after the page is finished rendering ... I haven't tested to verify, though

Answer (score 7):

It's not the most intuitive of things, but you can do it using NoScript's Application Boundaries Enforcer.

I explained how to block just Google Search's Javascript (to kill Google Instant without logging in while still allowing easy login and use on other Google sub-sites) at [How to make Google Search scriptless with NoScript/AdBlock?](https://superuser.com/questions/260475/how-to-make-google-search-scriptless-with-noscript-adblock/325939#325939)

You can also use it to lock scripts from sites like Facebook into the domain they come from, so scripts from Facebook will only load if you're actually **on** Facebook. (Good for killing off stuff like "Like This", "Tweet This", and Google Buzz buttons so you don't have to trust them as far as your privacy and browser responsiveness go):

```
# facebook.com containment rule
# This rule allows Facebook scripts objects and frames to be included only
# from Facebook pages
Site .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Accept from .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)

# twitter.com containment rule
# Like the Facebook rule, but for twitter
Site twitter.com .twitter.com twimg.com .twimg.com
Accept from twitter.com .twitter.com twimg.com .twimg.com
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)

# Google Buzz containment rule
# Like the Facebook rule, but for Google
Site ^https?://www\.google\.com/buzz/.*
Accept from google.com .google.com googleapis.com .googleapis.com
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to using the [blacklist functionality](http://noscript.net/features#blacklist). As opposed to the usual whitelist of sites that you allow.

Answer (score 1):

NoScript deals with "domains" rather then pages.

Generally no, [url=http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5468]Possible to enable scripts on one specific page?[/url].

Though there are a lot of "other" features that NoScript offers that may help (just don't ask me which, though I do seem to recall some discussion of an annoyance on a particular banks website.)

Comment: The formatting language used here is [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), so the inline syntax (not using footnotes) is `[link text](url)`

Answer (score 0):

Try AdBlock Plus.

I presume you have the addon already. Use "Open Blockable Items" to select and create a filter. Along with ABP Element Hiding Helper, this is how I clean up over-cluttered pages.