# How to make Google Search scriptless with NoScript/AdBlock?

Tags: firefox, adblock, noscript, google-search

How to configure AdBlock or NoScript to make Google Search scriptless, but not to break multitude of pages that use Google's scripts (like if I "forbid google.com" in NoScipt)

@related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13566/how-to-turn-off-googles-page-preview-in-search/13626#13626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NoScript's base functionality works domain-by-domain, but the Application Boundaries Enforcer (ABE) can work on specific URLs and it's flexible enough to do what you want.

Here's the USER rule I used to get decent searching without breaking the rest:

```
Site ^https://encrypted.google.com/(s|search)(\?.*|$)
Deny INC(SCRIPT,XHR)
Sandbox
```

Just add it at the end in `NoScript Options > Advanced > ABE > User`.

The `Site` line matches both the page you load and the URL used under the hood for Google Instant updates, so whether the combination of `Site` and `INC()` matches on the URL of the top-level request or the request being judged (NoScript's ABE docs aren't clear on this), it'll cause requests for new results without pressing Enter to fail.

The `SCRIPT` in the `INC()` may or may not ever get fired (see my comment about the lack of detail in the ABE docs) but, if it does, it explicitly blocks any external Javascript they may be pulling in.

Finally, the `Sandbox` line tells ABE to allow the request for the page itself... but to do it with Javascript disabled. It and the `Site` line may be the only ones you need, but I thought I'd play it safe.

If you want more details, the aforementioned docs are at http://noscript.net/abe/abe_rules.pdf